# Not able to authenticate CKAN using WSO2 IDM by ckanext-oauth2 plugin

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, fiware, ckan, wso2-identity-server

I am using CKAN 2.7.2.

I have added the following configurations in my development.ini file of ckan:

```
ckan.oauth2.authorization_endpoint = https://wso2IP/oauth2/authorize
ckan.oauth2.token_endpoint = https://wso2IP/oauth2/token
ckan.oauth2.profile_api_url = https://wso2IP/userinfo
ckan.oauth2.client_id = *client-id*
ckan.oauth2.client_secret = *clientsecret*
ckan.oauth2.profile_api_user_field = abc
ckan.oauth2.profile_api_mail_field = abc@gmail.com
```

Also, have exported the following while running ckan using paster serve :

```
export OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT=True
```

Also, I have added an application (ckan provider) in WSO2 Identity Server also with callback URL = (http://ckan-url:5000/oauth2/callback) where the CKAN instance is running (i.e a private IP of 172.30.66.XX type running on port 5000).

So, what configuration need to be done in WSO2 Identity Server and ckan development.ini file?

Also, configuring on both sides, I get the error ***Client authentication Failed*** in CKAN GUI.

---

I am using Ckan 2.7.2 , WSO2-IS 5.1 and ckanext-oauth2 (oauthlib==0.8.0) [image: v0.6.0]

will it be giving a problem in authentication process??Can it be a version dependency issue??

I have followed the given steps. Kindly correct if I am missing or doing something wrong:

I have used API store and published ckan application.

Entered the ckan callback url as http://oauth2/callback

Entered the generated client ID and client secret from step 1 in ckan configuration.

Also, made the given changes mentioned by you regarding claim configurations and ckanext-oauth2 configurations.

Now, it gives above error.or sometimes Invalid Client (Client Authentication Failed)

Inbound settings:

enter image description here

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Error Logs :

```
[2018-07-25 19:29:25,432]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2018-07-25 19:29:25,431+0530]
[2018-07-25 21:55:15,930]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.store.OperationCleanUpService} -  Session Operation Data cleanup task is running successfully for removing expired Operation Data
[2018-07-25 23:40:15,929]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.store.SessionCleanUpService} -  Session Data cleanup task is running successfully for removing expired Data
[2018-07-26 09:21:18,948]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2018-07-26 09:21:18,948+0530]
[2018-07-26 09:21:39,307]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged out at [2018-07-26 09:21:39,0306]
[2018-07-26 09:55:15,975]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.store.OperationCleanUpService} -  Session Operation Data cleanup task is running successfully for removing expired Operation Data
```

After configuring the settings I receive the following Message:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure about your application side configurations. But in the Identity Server side follow this https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/Adding+and+Configuring+a+Service+Provider to configure. Expand the section "Click here for details on how to configure inbound authentication" and in that "OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration". And the configurations you have done and if you see any error in IS logs, add them also to the question.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: thanks@MadurangaSiriwardena. I did the same in WSO2 IS , but was unsuccessful.I'll paste the screenshots asap.Also, do I need to fill inbound provisioning configuration also for the same (for oauth2)?

Comment: @MadurangaSiriwardena, do i need to make any Claim mapping setting in WSO2 IS according to the given configuration in CKAN.?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the log? And attach a screenshot of the inbound authentication configuration you have added.

Comment: @MadurangaSiriwardena added the configuration.

Comment: Any errors in the log?

Comment: No logs sir @MadurangaSiriwardena but earlier they were as shown above

Comment: Hi @MadurangaSiriwardena I have pasted the screenshot of the message I get after authorizing in WSO2-IS. If you can please help in it? Also, can you please tell what to enter in  OpenID Configuration? And when I changed my scope to in  'ckan.oauth2.scope=all info openid' . I recieve the Message as scope changed from all_info to default ?

Comment: If you are using authorization code grant type and if you have a endpoint that can handle the authorization code send in the last redirect at the callback you have specified, your OIDC configuration in the Identity Server is correct. Are you saying when you send "all info openid" as the scope, it is changed to default?

Comment: Hi @MadurangaSiriwardena can you please help me with configuring wso2-apim carbon management console with nginx. I have followed the official doc, but it only suggests about wso2-store and wso2-publisher. which are working fine but, I am unable to make carbon work with Nginx.

Comment: @Arnav, since this issue is not related to the question, better to create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Your application settings at WSO2-IS seems to be correct. The only thing to take into consideration, it is that `ckanext-oauth2` is only able to use the `Code` and, the `Refresh Token` grant types, so only those types need to be allowed.

Using this configuration for `ckanext-oauth2`:

```
ckan.oauth2.authorization_endpoint = https://wso2IP/oauth2/authorize
ckan.oauth2.token_endpoint = https://wso2IP/oauth2/token
ckan.oauth2.profile_api_url = https://wso2IP/userinfo
ckan.oauth2.client_id = *** OAuth Client Key from the Inbound Authentication Configuration at WSO2 ***
ckan.oauth2.client_secret = *** OAuth Client Secret from the Inbound Authentication Configuration at WSO2 ***
ckan.oauth2.scope = all_info openid
ckan.oauth2.profile_api_user_field = email
ckan.oauth2.profile_api_fullname_field = name
ckan.oauth2.profile_api_mail_field = email
```

and using your claim mapping configuration (`http://wso2.org/claims/fullname` and `http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress`); I was able to sign in into CKAN. I have tested using CKAN v2.7.4, v2.8.0 and v2.8.1; `ckanext-oauth2` v0.6.1 and WSO2-IS v5.5.0 (although it should work using WSO2-IS v5.1).

Comment: Hi @Álvaro , thank you so much for your inputs,but,despite following your instructions as it is. I was unable to authenticate the user and get an error:

**(Invalid Client)Client Authentication Failed** .

I am signing in with the user registered(username:admin) on WSO2 IS and also **assigned the user** admin to this application.(Service Provider(Ckan Application) in WSO2).

Can you please help ?I am using Ckan 2.7.2 and IS- v5.3

Comment: Hi @Alvaro , I have pasted the screenshot of the message I get after authorizing in WSO2-IS. If you  can please help in it?
Also, can you please tell what did you enter in OpenID Configuration?
And when I changed my scope to in 'ckan.oauth2.scope=all info openid' . I recieve the Message as scope changed from **all_info to default** ?

Comment: Hi @Alvaro, when I made the above changes, I get a message on CKAN as "scope changed from all_info to default" and the user is not logged in.?